# Agregar lógica de base de datos - relaciones SQL

Tags: sql, relaciones

una pregunta en base a una nueva funcionalidad que necesito implementar. Partiendo de la siguiente imagen para que sea más claro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la tabla propiedades que segmenta los tipos de propiedades hasta el momento tenía servicios generales en común.

Ahora quisiera que al seleccionar por ejemplo casa me muestre servicios específicos a una casa y así sucesivamente.

Los servicios de una casa son distintos a lo de los departamentos, ph, quinta.

Pensaba en agregar una relación a cada uno, de uno a mucho por ejemplo casa_servicio, departamento_servicio, ph_servicio etc.

Sería la manera apropiada? o tendría que pensarlo de otra manera?

Agradezco muchísimo su tiempo en mi consulta.

Comment: Quizas hay que cambiar un poco el sentido de las preguntas al final, no es lo "apropiado", sino lo que la teoria de bases relacionales diga. Es que apropiado podria malinterpretarse como la opinion de cada uno. Al final, este tipo de preguntas son interesantes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que una consulta a tu base de datos pueda llevarse a cabo correctamente, las relaciones deberian ser

1. las Propiedades pueden tener un tipo de propiedad, y el Tipo de Propiedad puede pertenecer a muchas propiedades;
2. las Propiedades pueden tener muchos Servicios, y los Servicios pueden pertenecer a muchas propiedades

Asi, cuando ejecutes tu consulta, puedes obtener los servicios de una propiedad, dependiendo de su tipo. En un ejemplo imaginario, muy basicamente y a grandes rasgos, lo que haria un ORM seria:

```
a. SELECT * FROM propiedad WHERE propiedad.tipo = 1 (alli ya tienes tu propiedad y el tipo de propiedad que quieras)
b. SELECT * FROM servicio, propiedad_servicio as ps WHERE ps.propiedad_id = propiedad.id AND ps.servicio_id = servicio.id
c. Se empaqueta todo en un objeto y se devuelve para ser usado como quieras
```

El resultado sera que obtendras la informacion de tu propiedad y de sus servicios especificos.

Comment: Hola Kenny, gracias por tu respuesta clarificadora, una consulta más. Se debería utilizar una tabla pivot?

Comment: En mi mente, si deberia usarse una tabla pivot, porque entiendo que un servicio puede pertenecer a varias propiedades. Pero si no fuera el caso, una relacion de uno a muchos seria suficiente.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!! buen finde!